# why is it giving me errors when I input decimal hours?

Tags: java

sorry guys this is my first week at programming and my task is to design a program that calculates regular pay and overtime pay based on user input, but when I put 5.5 in hours or rates it gives me errors I don't really understand why

if there is way to fix the error then how do you get rid of .0 at the end of output integers? thanks a bunch, teacher just assumed we know all the stuff when I took AP CS, this is the review from last years "intro class" so I'm bit overwhelmed, if still have some time left, can you please explain the mechanism behind "double"? to my understanding so far it means you can use decimals as opposed to int where you can only put integers code here

`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Salary
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1, s2;
            double number1, number2;

            s1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours worked");
            s2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the rates per hour");

            number1 = Integer.parseInt ( s1); 
            number2 = Integer.parseInt ( s2); 

            double elseregularp = ( 40*number2);
            double regularp = ( number1*number2);
            double othours = (number1-40);
            double othourspay = ( number2* 15/10.0);


            if( number1 <= 40)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU WORKED "+number1+" HOURS" );
                System.out.println("YOU EARNED $"+number1 * number2+" REGULAR PAY");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("YOU WORKED " + number1+" HOURS");
                System.out.println("YOU EARNED $"+elseregularp+" REGULAR PAY");
                System.out.println("AND $" +(othours)*(othourspay)+ " IN OVERTIME");
                System.out.println("YOUR TOTAL CHECK IS $" + ((elseregularp)+(othours)*(othourspay)));
            }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: The `Integer.parseInt(...)` method parses only integer Strings, not floating point math Strings. For that you'd need `Double.parseDouble(...)`.

Comment: Firstly, *always* tell us your errors. No one wants to guess or try to read code to figure it out. Secondly, identify the corresponding lines of code to those given in those errors. Thirdly, read those errors and try to figure them out. Most are not hard to understand and are self descriptive. Lastly, look at the code and see if what you're doing even makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

integer.parseInt(...) is accepting a string value which is not the correct input for it. So change it to parseDouble so that it works correctly.

Your final code after modification.

integer.parseInt (...) is changed to Double.parseDouble(...)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Salary
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1, s2;
        double number1, number2;

        s1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours worked");
        s2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the rates per hour");

       // number1 = Integer.parseInt ( s1); 
       // number2 = Integer.parseInt ( s2); 
        number1=Double.parseDouble(s1);
        number2=Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double elseregularp = ( 40*number2);
        double regularp = ( number1*number2);
        double othours = (number1-40);
        double othourspay = ( number2* 15/10.0);


        if( number1 <= 40)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU WORKED "+number1+" HOURS" );
            System.out.println("YOU EARNED $"+number1 * number2+" REGULAR PAY");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("YOU WORKED " + number1+" HOURS");
            System.out.println("YOU EARNED $"+elseregularp+" REGULAR PAY");
            System.out.println("AND $" +(othours)*(othourspay)+ " IN OVERTIME");
            System.out.println("YOUR TOTAL CHECK IS $" + ((elseregularp)+(othours)*(othourspay)));
        }
}
```

}